# Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (unable to verify the first certificate),

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

**Hello, I´m trying to deploy again a simple service that was working fine (hello world)**

```
C:\Users\userssss\hola-mundo>sls invoke -f hello -s dev
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": "{\n  \"message\": \"Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!\",\n  \"input\": {}\n}"
}
```

**But suddenly it started to give error.  **
**I tried to set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 but still doing errors**
**Could you help me please, just starting to learn how to use AWS LAMBDA,thank you**

```
C:\Users\userssss\hola-mundo>sls invoke -f hello -s dev
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (unable to verify the first certificate), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 1 of 4
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (unable to verify the first certificate), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 2 of 4
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (unable to verify the first certificate), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 3 of 4
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (unable to verify the first certificate), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 4 of 4
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
  unable to verify the first certificate
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          win32
     Node Version:              12.13.1
     Framework Version:         1.58.0
     Plugin Version:            3.2.5
     SDK Version:               2.2.1
     Components Core Version:   1.1.2
     Components CLI Version:    1.4.0
C:\Users\userssss\hola-mundo>sls deploy
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (unable to verify the first certificate), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 1 of 4
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (unable to verify the first certificate), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 2 of 4
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (unable to verify the first certificate), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 3 of 4
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (unable to verify the first certificate), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 4 of 4
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
  unable to verify the first certificate
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          win32
     Node Version:              12.13.1
     Framework Version:         1.58.0
     Plugin Version:            3.2.5
     SDK Version:               2.2.1
     Components Core Version:   1.1.2
     Components CLI Version:    1.4.0``
```

Comment: What's your serverless version

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're behind a corporate firewall of some kind? If so, there are some documented options here: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3256

First I'd try `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 sls deploy`. If that works, you can try some of the permanent solutions I linked to.

Comment: my nodejs is a Windows....C:\Users\userssssss\MiProgTest1>NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 sls deploy
'NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Added this in the env windows ... But still have this error : C:\Users\userssss\hola-mundo>sls deploy
(node:20248) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (unable to verify the first certificate), sleeping for ~6 seconds. Try 1 of 4
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (unable to verify the first certificate),